# How to create button at run time on specified location inside frame layout android?

Tags: android

I am trying to create button at runtime.I am getting the coordinate and height,width of button from backend and I have to create button at same location on run time.I have used following code.

```
Button btn=new Button(getApplicationContext());
btn.setText("CLICK ME");
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams param = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams( 121,  58,  50,  50);
btn.setLayoutParams(param);
mParentView.addView(btn);
```

My xml is

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ViewFlipper>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/header_fragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.sdei.presentationapp.activity.PresentationModeTopBar"
        tools:layout="@layout/presentation_top_bar" />
</FrameLayout>
```

here the parentview is framelayout.

I am able to create the button but the problem is it is created always at top left corner,no matter what coordinate we pass.Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the **mParentView** i mean **Linear**, ....

Comment: Please attach the xml layout of your activity/fragment, so we can more easily see the issue

Comment: I have edited the code.You can check now.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set button at your desired position in framelayout only possible in absolute layout. but you can use margin with respect to your left and top which will work like your (x, y) coordinates.

```
// First create your button:

 Button test_button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
 test_button.setText("test");

// Then create layout params for you buttons.

 FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(100, 100); // Button width and button height.
 lp.leftMargin = 200; // your X coordinate.
 lp.topMargin = 300;  // your Y coordinate.

// Then find layout and add button on it.

 FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FrameLayout1);
 layout.addView(test_button, lp);
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have not compile this code, so change as per your layout.

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
fl .setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);

Button okButton=new Button(this);
okButton.setId(ok_id)
okButton.setText("some text");
```

- See one reference link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524589/how-can-we-add-buttons-at-dynamic-positions-in-layout)

Answer (score 0):

The `absolute layout` class is `deprecated`, you are encouraged to `use Frame Layout or Relative layout instead`.
The reason of that is it won’t be compatible with all the android phones as they have different screen sizes and resolutions.
Absolute layout lays widgets by specifying their exact X and Y positions. In android the origin (0,0) coordinate is located at the `top left` of the screen. By default, if you define any control in absolute layout without defining it’s x,y coordinates, it will be placed in the origin point at (x,y)=(0,0);

Thus your defined position for `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams` is not working properly.
As you are using FrameLayout then you can try the following way-

```
// declare and initialize LayoutParams for the framelayout
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

// decide upon the positioning of the button //
// you will likely need to use the screen size to position the
// button anywhere other than the four corners
params.setMargins(.., .., .., ..);

// use static constants from the Gravity class
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
btn.setLayoutParams(params);
mParentView.addView(btn);
```

Comment: also you can used Relative Layout instead of FrameLayout.

Comment: Ok,is there any way to do this without adding margins.I mean by giving the coordinate

Comment: If you don't want to mention margin then don't use it.

Comment: Then how can i set it at the desired location

Comment: Is any rule applicable to display your generated button like below/right_of "someId"?

Comment: No,i have only coordinate and height width of button

Comment: @swati have you follow my answer ?

Comment: Can you try btn.setX() and btn.setY(), if it works then fine else you need to set the x and Y in FrameLayout then you need to set the FrameLayout to the button.