# Changing button's position in Android

Tags: java, android, button, position

My first question was to click through layout. I solved it out.

Now my question is how to set button's position at desired location?

My application's minimum api level is 8 (I can't set *getX()* or *getLeft()*)

Test XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<Button android:id="@+id/buttonx" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="X" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Acitivty code:

```
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class Test extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED); getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD); getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL); requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        Button xclose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonx);
        xclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

any way to change button's position dynamically or programatically?

Comment: you will get many examples on this see this [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683727/layout-with-dynamic-position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) by Jake Wharton to use setX() and setY() (and many other properties).
This library ports back the Honeycomb-Animation Framework to api level 1!

If that doesn't work, you could create your own ViewGroup and measure/layout the children yourself. More information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html).

EDIT: Also, View.getLeft()/getTop()/... is available since api level 1. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLeft%28%29)

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you tell me how to import and use setLeft() using NineOldAndroids?

Comment: You should not call setLeft(), the framework will do that for you. You need to create a custom `View` that will override `onMeasure()` and `onLayout()`. Inside `onLayout()` you can call `this.myButton.layout(left,top,right,bottom);` to place the button wherever you want inside your custom view. More info here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYtB6mlu7vA

Answer (score 1):

If you need to align the views in Linear Layout Please read about gravity and layout_gravity properties.

You have another layout like Relative layout. It will give you more properties for view alignment.ex:layout_alignLeft,layout_alignParentLeft etc...

Study about it and use it however you want....Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding or margin in code for example

```
 xclose.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
```

At the time of onclick u try this

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where do you want to locate your button, but you should look into FrameLayout (which will let you put the button anywhere in your layout).

Answer (score 0):

Using Android, you usually have three layout options as detailed in the [Layouts | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#CommonLayouts) notes. The [Linear Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) gives you the option to declare elements and chain them either horizontally or vertically. The [Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html), which is what I believe you need, allows you to freely define the position of an element relative to another element, and the [Web View](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) is usually used to show web related content.

As I said, I believe the [Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) is what you are looking for. Have a look at [this example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html#Example) which neatly outlines how to use the different alignment options to place elements. You will not there are two major categories. The first lets you align your element with a parent element which is handy if you want to move elements left, right, top, bottom, or centre. The second lets you define the alignment in regard to elements on the same level by specifying that your element be, for example, `android:layout_toLeftOf` or `android:layout_below`. You can combine all of these to get the desired result.

I am well aware that there are many options to achieve the result but I found this to be quite simple and usually sufficient to achieve visually attractive layouts.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/blur2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<Button android:id="@+id/buttonx" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="X" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Make sure it's relative, not Linearlayout, because on relative it would allow you to move buttons easily.